# Where do i put the static sound files in ionic2 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

i'm trying to play some sound files from button click in ionic2 app using mediaplugin http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/mediaplugin/

```
const file = new MediaPlugin('path/to/file.mp3', onStatusUpdate);
```

i have the 'click.wav' file in '/src/assets/sound/' directory, now how do the access this file in the MediaPlugin() ?? and am i putting the file in the right directory?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use *cordova.file.externalDataDirectory* then you can find your sound file on the phone under *Android/data/yourapplication/files* folder.

```
this.filePath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;

this.mediaPlugin = new MediaPlugin(this.filePath + this.directoryName + "/" + this.actualAudioFileName);
```

You can start a playback with the following code, after you already recorded one

```
this.mediaPlugin.play();
```

Check this pretty good [tutorial](http://www.erikschierboom.com/2016/09/02/ionic2-audio-recorder/).

Edit:
[Here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/) you can check path of directories, if you want to create a cross platform application